# When returning to Home Page friend request displays 0

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to create a social networking site and am facing a problem regarding accepting and rejecting Friend Requests. Here's the code that I've used for accepting a Friend Request:

```
<body>
<%!
    Connection conn;
    int user_id;
    int send_id;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
%>
<%
    HttpSession session2 = request.getSession(false);
    user_id = (Integer)session2.getAttribute("id");
    send_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("snd_id"));
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        out.print(e);
    }

    try {
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","vishal");
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("create table if not exists Friends(requested int, accepted int)");
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Friends values(?,?)");
        pstmt.setInt(1,send_id);
        pstmt.setInt(2,user_id);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from PendingRequest where sender_id=? and receiver_id = ?");
        pstmt.setInt(1,send_id);
        pstmt.setInt(2,user_id);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }

    catch(SQLException e) {
        out.print(e);
    }

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
    rd.include(request,response);
%>
```

Now when the code is redirecting the user to the"home.jsp" page, the Friend Request column shows 0 requests, although in the database there are 2 to 3 pending requests.

Can anybody please resolve this problem?

Here is the code which is printing the number of friend requests:

```
<%
try
{
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","vishal");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("create table if not exists PendingRequest(sender_id int, receiver_id int)");
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        PreparedStatement pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("select count(sender_id) from PendingRequest where receiver_id=?");
        pstmt2.setInt(1,user_id);
        ResultSet rst = pstmt2.executeQuery();
        if(rst.next())
            cnt=rst.getInt(1);
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select sender_id from PendingRequest where receiver_id=?");
        pstmt.setInt(1,user_id);
        rst = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rst.next())
        {
            send[i] = rst.getInt(1);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        out.print(e);
    }
%>
Friend Requests&nbsp;(<%=cnt%>)
```

Comment: Where is the code to display the requests ?

Comment: @sankrish I've updated my code to display the number of Friend Requests.

Comment: Check whether you have data in the columns `sender_id` and  `receiver_id`? Also check whether you have more than one row for `sender_id` And also check whether you have any exception?

Comment: @sankrish I've checked everything and I realise that correct changes are made in the Databases.Also, although when redirected to "home.jsp" it isn't displaying correct values but when I login after logging out, it displays correct values. Is there any problem with these two statements:

Comment: RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
rd.include(request,response);    ????

Comment: Yes i guess . Check for your prepared statements , you can manually pass the values for the `receiver_id` to check

Comment: replace this `rd.include(request,response); ???? ` by `rd.forward(request,response); ???? `

Comment: @sankrish Tried...But no luck.The same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was redirecting to "home.jsp" which redirects to webpage "home.jsp" directly without anyone logging on.So, I had to pass the login-id and password as a query string as shown:

```
String lnk = "/home.jsp?login="+email+"&pass="+password;
pageContext.forward(lnk);
```

And I've retrieved the login-id and password as:

```
String email = (String)session2.getAttribute("email");
String password = (String)session2.getAttribute("password");
```

which I've placed inside a Sriplet.